# In Meteor How to copy data between templates?

Tags: meteor

I'm new to both meteor and JS.

I created a meteor app like this:

```
cd /tmp/
meteor create hello
cd hello
```

In hello.html I wrote this

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> t1}}
  {{> t2}}
</body>
```

Then I added these templates:

```
<template name='t1'>
<span id='t1'>hello</span>
</template>
```

---

```
<template name='t2'>
<span id='t2'>world</span>
</template>
```

Then I wrote syntax inside of hello.js to get text from the DOM:

```
Template.t1.onRendered( function() {
  mytext = $('span#t1').html() });
```

According to the debugger-console in my browser,
the above syntax works okay.

The debugger tells me that mytext == 'hello'

Question: How to share the mytext value with other parts of my Meteor app?

As written, mytext is stuck inside my anonymous function.

For example how would I make this call work:

```
$('span#t2').html(mytext)
```

??

Comment: So the actual question isn't _"How to extract HTML?"_ since you already did that easily. A better question would be _"How to share a value between different parts of a Meteor app?"_. Please confirm and edit accordingly. If I am correct and you are asking how to share values between a Meteor App, know that this question has already been answered a lot (try searching for `Session`).

Comment: In Meteor what is size constraint of session? I see no answer in Google or the docs. In other web frameworks, session should stay small. I assume that jquery has access to several MB of RAM.  If session has access several MB of RAM, then session would work well for me. If it does not, perhaps I should search for the Meteor API call which calls-back when all the templates have rendered.  In that call-back I would use jquery to interact with the DOM.

Comment: Again, please edit your question. In its current form it seems to ask about extracting HTML when it's really just about sharing data in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to reactively watch your variable. An easy out-of-the-box solution for this is to use the [Session variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session).  You can do it pretty easily like so:

```
Template.t1.onRendered( function() {
  Session.set('mytext', $('span#t1').html()); 
});
```

Then in your second template, define and reference helper that returns that variable:

```
<!--html-->
<template name='t2'>
  <span id='t2'>{{getMyText}}</span>
</template>

//js
Template.t2.helpers({
  getMyText: function() { return Session.get('mytext'); }
});
```

The Session variable is reactive, so when the first template renders and sets the value of `Session.mytext`, the helper's result will be invalidated and the second template will update.